# concat two mysql tables and convert it to json with php

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I'm using PHP with PDO for a project
I have the following two tables in my database.

`Category`

```
CategoryID  | Name          | CategoryCode  
1           | Fixed         | FA    
2           | Consumable    | CA    
3           | Intangible    | IA
```

`Type`

```
TypeID | CategoryID | Name                              | TypeCode  
1      | 1          | Furniture                         | FU    
2      | 1          | Computers & Computer Peripherals  | CP    
3      | 1          | Electrical Appliances             | EA    
4      | 1          | Machinery                         | MA    
5      | 2          | Computer Peripherals              | PE    
6      | 3          | Software                          | SW
```

I need to get a output like below from the select operation. I have tried it with group concat and then fecthAll(), but it doesn't give me the result in correct JSON

`Output`

```
[
  {
    "CategoryID": 1,
    "Name": "Fixed",
    "CategoryCode": "FA",
    "Types": [
      {
        "TypeID": 1,
        "Name": "Furniture",
        "TypeCode": "FU"
      },
      {
        "TypeID": 2,
        "Name": "Computers & Computer Peripherals",
        "TypeCode": "CP"
      },
      {
        "TypeID": 3,
        "Name": "Electrical Appliances",
        "TypeCode": "EA"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "CategoryID": 2,
    "Name": "Consumable",
    "CategoryCode": "CA",
    "Types": [
      {
        "TypeID": 5,
        "Name": "Computer Peripherals",
        "TypeCode": "PE"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Please post your attempted query.

Comment: And please run `SELECT version();` to check specific MySQL version.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out this way to get my intended output

```
protected function getCategories(){
        $dbConnection = $this->connect();
        $catSql = 'SELECT * FROM `category`';
        $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare($catSql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $output = array();
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $line = array("CategoryID" => $row['CategoryID'], "CategoryName" => $row['Name'], "CategoryCode" => $row['CategoryCode']);
            $typeSQL =  'SELECT
                    TypeID,
                    Name,
                    TypeCode
                FROM type
                WHERE
                    CategoryID = ' . $row['CategoryID'];
            $stmt2 = $dbConnection->prepare($typeSQL);
            $stmt2->execute();
            $types = $stmt2->fetchAll();
            $typeArray = array();
            foreach ($types as $type) {
                $typeLine = array("TypeID" => $type['TypeID'], "TypeName" => $type['Name'], "TypeCode" => $type['TypeCode']);
                array_push($typeArray, $typeLine);
            }
            $line['Types'] = $typeArray;
            array_push($output, $line);
        }
        return json_encode($output);
    }
```